# Could not load file or assembly error when inheriting class from DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, vsto

`EF Core` works fine on my `WPF .NET Framework 4.8` app. But when I try the `EF Core` on my [Microsoft Office VSTO Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019) project, I get the following error after I inherit a class from `DbContext` class:

**Question**: What is causing the error and how can we resolve it?

**Remark**:

On `VS2019 v 16.5.5`, I'm using this [exact same official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=visual-studio) on my `WPF .NET Framework 4.8` and on `VSTO Add-in` project. But only `public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{.....}` part of the class file fails on VSTO project. If I take this class out, the project compiles fine. But as we know, for `EF` to work, the `DbContext` is the most important (and mandatory) class to have.

**Summary of the Error**:

```
"FindRibbons" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyWORDAddIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'MyWORDAddIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Server stack trace:

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
...........
..........
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. MyWORDAddIn
```

Comment: Have you tried to enable logging as the error message states? To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I would avoid playing with registry keys.

Comment: It is for enabling logging in the VSTO engine.